# SQL Server XML formatting

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I've been stuck on this problem for almost 2 days.. at the very bottom is what I've come up with, but I can't seem to get the formatting right. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the problem:

```
--Axis data
create TABLE tmpPrimaryAxisLeaves 
(
     NodeID int, 
     NodeLabel nvarchar(max)
)

create TABLE tmpSecondaryAxisLeaves  
(
     NodeID int, 
     NodeLabel nvarchar(max)
)

create TABLE tmpTertiaryAxisLeaves 
(
     NodeID int, 
     NodeLabel nvarchar(max)
)

INSERT INTO tmpPrimaryAxisLeaves (NodeID, NodeLabel) 
    SELECT 1, 'North America' UNION
    SELECT 2, 'South America' UNION
    SELECT 3, 'EU' UNION
    SELECT 4, 'Africa' UNION
    SELECT 5, 'Russia'

INSERT INTO tmpSecondaryAxisLeaves (NodeID, NodeLabel) 
    SELECT 10, 'Peter Pan' UNION
    SELECT 20, 'Groot' UNION
    SELECT 30, 'Batman' 

INSERT INTO tmpTertiaryAxisLeaves (NodeID, NodeLabel) 
    SELECT 2, 'Shirts' UNION
    SELECT 4, 'Pants' UNION
    SELECT 6, 'Hats' 

--Contract data
create table tmpContracts 
(
     StartDate datetime, 
     EndDate datetime, 
     PrimaryAxisID int, 
     SecondaryAxisID int, 
     TertiaryAxisID int, 
     LanguageID int
)

INSERT INTO tmpContracts (StartDate, EndDate, PrimaryAxisID, SecondaryAxisID, TertiaryAxisID, LanguageID)
  SELECT '1/1/2010', '1/1/2018', 1, 20, 2, 1 UNION
  SELECT '1/1/2010', '1/1/2018', 1, 20, 2, 2 UNION
  SELECT '1/1/2010', '1/1/2018', 1, 20, 2, 5 UNION
  SELECT '1/1/2010', '1/1/2018', 1, 20, 6, 1 UNION
  SELECT '1/1/2010', '1/1/2018', 1, 20, 6, 2 UNION
  SELECT '1/1/2010', '1/1/2018', 1, 20, 6, 5 UNION
  SELECT '1/1/2011', '1/1/2020', 2, 20, 2, 1 UNION
  SELECT '1/1/2011', '1/1/2020', 2, 20, 2, 3 UNION
  SELECT '1/1/2011', '1/1/2020', 2, 20, 4, 1 UNION
  SELECT '1/1/2011', '1/1/2020', 2, 20, 4, 3 UNION
  SELECT '1/1/2011', '1/1/2020', 2, 20, 4, 5 UNION
  SELECT '1/1/2011', '1/1/2020', 3, 30, 2, 1 UNION
  SELECT '1/1/2011', '1/1/2020', 4, 30, 6, 1

--Langauges
create table tmpLanguages 
(
     LanguageID int, 
     Name nvarchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO tmpLanguages
   SELECT 1, 'English' UNION
   SELECT 2, 'Spanish' UNION
   SELECT 3, 'French' UNION
   SELECT 4, 'Russia' UNION
   SELECT 5, 'Dutch'
```

Write a query that will take the above data and return XML in the following format with the correct values in each place indicated ("[XXXXX]")  Results should like this:

```
<AvailabiltyList>
  <PrimaryNode>
    <NodeID>[PrimaryAxis.NodeID]</NodeID>
    <NodeLabel>[PrimaryAxis.NodeLabel]</NodeLabel>
    <SecondaryAxis>
      <SecondaryNode>
        <NodeID>[SecondaryAxis.NodeID]</NodeID>
        <NodeLabel>[SecondaryAxis.NodeLabel]</NodeLabel>
        <TertiaryAxis>
          <TertiaryNode>
            <NodeID>[TertiaryAxis.NodeID]</NodeID>
            <NodeLabel>[TertiaryAxis.NodeLabel]</NodeLabel>
            <ContractData>
              <ContractDataPoint>
                <ContractStart>[Contracts.StartDate]</ContractStart>
                <ContractEnd>[Contracts.EndDate]</ContractEnd>
              </ContractDataPoint>
            </ContractData>
            <Languages>[Comma delimited list of languages for the matching contracts]</Languages>
          </TertiaryNode>
          <TertiaryNode>....</TertiaryNode>
          <TertiaryNode>....</TertiaryNode>
          <TertiaryNode>....</TertiaryNode>
        </TertiaryAxis>
      </SecondaryNode>
      <SecondaryNode>...</SecondaryNode>
      <SecondaryNode>...</SecondaryNode>
      <SecondaryNode>...</SecondaryNode>
      <SecondaryNode>...</SecondaryNode>
  </PrimaryNode>
  <PrimaryNode>...</PrimaryNode>
  <PrimaryNode>...</PrimaryNode>
  <PrimaryNode>...</PrimaryNode>
</AvailabilityList>
```

Here is what I've come up with..but I can't seem to get the formatting right.

```
select 
    PrimaryNode.NodeID as pnode,
    PrimaryNode.NodeLabel as plabel,
    SecondaryNode.NodeID as snode,
    SecondaryNode.NodeLabel as slabel,
    TertiaryNode.NodeID as tnode,
    TertiaryNode.NodeLabel as tlable, 
    ContractDataPoint.StartDate, 
    ContractDataPoint.EndDate
from 
    tmpContracts ContractDataPoint 
left join 
    tmpPrimaryAxisLeaves PrimaryNode on ContractDataPoint.PrimaryAxisID = PrimaryNode.NodeID
inner join 
    tmpSecondaryAxisLeaves SecondaryNode on     ContractDataPoint.SecondaryAxisID = SecondaryNode.NodeID
inner join 
    tmpTertiaryAxisLeaves TertiaryNode on        ContractDataPoint.TertiaryAxisID = TertiaryNode.NodeID
group by 
    PrimaryNode.NodeID, PrimaryNode.NodeLabel,
    SecondaryNode.NodeID, SecondaryNode.NodeLabel,
    TertiaryNode.NodeID, TertiaryNode.NodeLabel, 
    ContractDataPoint.StartDate, ContractDataPoint.EndDate
for xml auto, Root('AvailabiltyList'), Elements
```

My results:

```
<AvailabiltyList>
    <PrimaryNode>
        <pnode>1</pnode>
        <plabel>North America</plabel>
        <SecondaryNode>
          <snode>20</snode>
          <slabel>Groot</slabel>
      <TertiaryNode>
        <tnode>2</tnode>
        <tlable>Shirts</tlable>
        <ContractDataPoint>
          <StartDate>2010-01-01T00:00:00</StartDate>
          <EndDate>2018-01-01T00:00:00</EndDate>
        </ContractDataPoint>
      </TertiaryNode>
      <TertiaryNode>
        <tnode>6</tnode>
        <tlable>Hats</tlable>
        <ContractDataPoint>
          <StartDate>2010-01-01T00:00:00</StartDate>
          <EndDate>2018-01-01T00:00:00</EndDate>
        </ContractDataPoint>
      </TertiaryNode>
    </SecondaryNode>
  </PrimaryNode>
  <PrimaryNode>
    <pnode>2</pnode>
    <plabel>South America</plabel>
    <SecondaryNode>
      <snode>20</snode>
      <slabel>Groot</slabel>
      <TertiaryNode>
        <tnode>2</tnode>
        <tlable>Shirts</tlable>
        <ContractDataPoint>
          <StartDate>2011-01-01T00:00:00</StartDate>
          <EndDate>2020-01-01T00:00:00</EndDate>
        </ContractDataPoint>
      </TertiaryNode>
      <TertiaryNode>
        <tnode>4</tnode>
        <tlable>Pants</tlable>
        <ContractDataPoint>
          <StartDate>2011-01-01T00:00:00</StartDate>
          <EndDate>2020-01-01T00:00:00</EndDate>
        </ContractDataPoint>
      </TertiaryNode>
    </SecondaryNode>
  </PrimaryNode>
  <PrimaryNode>
    <pnode>3</pnode>
    <plabel>EU</plabel>
    <SecondaryNode>
      <snode>30</snode>
      <slabel>Batman</slabel>
      <TertiaryNode>
        <tnode>2</tnode>
        <tlable>Shirts</tlable>
        <ContractDataPoint>
          <StartDate>2011-01-01T00:00:00</StartDate>
          <EndDate>2020-01-01T00:00:00</EndDate>
        </ContractDataPoint>
      </TertiaryNode>
    </SecondaryNode>
  </PrimaryNode>
  <PrimaryNode>
    <pnode>4</pnode>
    <plabel>Africa</plabel>
    <SecondaryNode>
      <snode>30</snode>
      <slabel>Batman</slabel>
      <TertiaryNode>
        <tnode>6</tnode>
        <tlable>Hats</tlable>
        <ContractDataPoint>
          <StartDate>2011-01-01T00:00:00</StartDate>
          <EndDate>2020-01-01T00:00:00</EndDate>
        </ContractDataPoint>
      </TertiaryNode>
    </SecondaryNode>
  </PrimaryNode>
</AvailabiltyList>
```

Comment: can you show the desired output format? What exactly is wrong at the moment?

Comment: Hello...I just added what it should look like above...Right after Results should look like this statement

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

**Create a udf to get the languages**

```
CREATE FUNCATION udfAxisLanguage
(@pNodeId  INT
,@sNodeId  INT
,@tNodeId  INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @retLang VARCHAR(100)   
select  
    @retLang = COALESCE(@retLang + ',','') + lang.name
from 
    tmpContracts ContractDataPoint 
left join 
    tmpPrimaryAxisLeaves PrimaryNode on ContractDataPoint.PrimaryAxisID = PrimaryNode.NodeID
inner join 
    tmpSecondaryAxisLeaves SecondaryNode on     ContractDataPoint.SecondaryAxisID = SecondaryNode.NodeID
inner join 
    tmpTertiaryAxisLeaves TertiaryNode on        ContractDataPoint.TertiaryAxisID = TertiaryNode.NodeID
inner join tmpLanguages lang on ContractDataPoint.languageid = lang.languageId
WHERE PrimaryNode.NodeID = @pNodeId
AND   SecondaryNode.NodeID = @sNodeId
AND   TertiaryNode.NodeID = @tNodeId
;

RETURN @retLang ;
END ;
```

**Now use the above udf in your query, like this**

```
select 
    PrimaryNode.NodeID as pnode,
    PrimaryNode.NodeLabel as plabel,
    SecondaryNode.NodeID as snode,
    SecondaryNode.NodeLabel as slabel,
    TertiaryNode.NodeID as tnode,
    TertiaryNode.NodeLabel as tlable, 
    ContractDataPoint.StartDate, 
    ContractDataPoint.EndDate,
    dbo.udfAxisLanguage(PrimaryNode.NodeID,SecondaryNode.NodeID,TertiaryNode.NodeID) Name
from 
    tmpContracts ContractDataPoint 
left join 
    tmpPrimaryAxisLeaves PrimaryNode on ContractDataPoint.PrimaryAxisID = PrimaryNode.NodeID
inner join 
    tmpSecondaryAxisLeaves SecondaryNode on     ContractDataPoint.SecondaryAxisID = SecondaryNode.NodeID
inner join 
    tmpTertiaryAxisLeaves TertiaryNode on        ContractDataPoint.TertiaryAxisID = TertiaryNode.NodeID
group by 
    PrimaryNode.NodeID, PrimaryNode.NodeLabel,
    SecondaryNode.NodeID, SecondaryNode.NodeLabel,
    TertiaryNode.NodeID, TertiaryNode.NodeLabel, 
    ContractDataPoint.StartDate, ContractDataPoint.EndDate
    ,dbo.udfAxisLanguage(PrimaryNode.NodeID,SecondaryNode.NodeID,TertiaryNode.NodeID)
for xml auto, Root('AvailabiltyList'), Elements
```